# How to read / download SMS from Huawei E5377T mobile router?

Tags: linux, wireless-router, sms, sim

The device shows there are 8 messages but there is no option to read those.

I have tried to remove the SIM card and place it in a mobile phone but it seems that router does not store messages into the SIM but instead into its internal memory.

Is there any way to have those messages read or downloaded or transferred into the SIM card?

***Note***: using Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no direct way of downloading (SMS) messages. You either have to use the mobile App or the web interface while being connected to the device's Wifi to read messages. As for transferring messages to the SIM card, I don't think that's possible.

As you're using a Linux machine, the web interface (usually at 192.168.8.1) would be the simplest option.

Comment: This seems to be adequate solution for me. How come I never thought about the web ui myself :) Unfortunately I now struggle with the admin password. There is the default password printed in the sticker behind battery but not that neiher any defaults I have found this far has worked. And I fear that factory reset will wipe the messages also.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with retreiving the Admin password.

Comment: Yes of course you cannot. I guess there is nothing too important in those messages. I bought the device used and was too foolish to reset it at the beginning b4 inserting my secondary number SIM. All the other settings were default. But now I do a factory reset whatever happens,